# determining what files a package updates / copying software between machines

Tags: package-management, clipboard, install-from-source, compiling

How do I determine which files comprise an application (built from source, not from a repo), so I can copy it?

I built an application from source, but because the libraries it needed to build were not compatible with the system that will run it, I had to build it in a VM. (I am sure there is some way of maintaining two different sets of libs, but I don't know how).

It doesn't need those updated libraries to run, so I need to find out what I need to copy.

I thought of capturing the output of `sudo make install`, but that doesn't seem to work. I could do a diff of files on the whole system but there must be an easier way? Maybe if I pack it into a .deb or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I determine which files comprise an application (built from source, not from a repo), so I can copy it?

The easy solution for most cases is to simply use `checkinstall`, which will create a .deb file that you can not only install on other (compatible) systems, but also allows you to uninstall the package.

- `sudo apt-get install checkinstall -y`
- When done with `make`, run `checkinstall` instead of `make install`
- *checkinstall* will install your application AND give you a .deb file in the current (source) folder which you can simply copy and install on other systems with `dpkg -i`
- Use `dpkg -r application-name` to remove the application at any time (should also work from Synaptic)

Please see this [community help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) and the [author's home page](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/) if you need more information.